# R language: How to solve matrix for unknown constant

Tags: r

Using R: How do I enter an unknown constant 'h' in an augmented matrix so R can calculate the Reduced Row-Echelon Form? i.e. to find the value h that makes the augmented matrix consistent.

```
| 1  h  4 | 
| 3  6  8 |


A = matrix(
  c(1,h,4,3,6,8), 
  nrow = 2,             
  ncol = 3,             
  byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you explain: 1. what you mean by the `| ... |` notation. 2. What you mean by "solve the matrix". 3. What you mean by "the system is consistent".

Comment: It is a Linear Algebra question. | ... | is a matrix. "solve the matrix" means determine the value of h so that the matrix is consistent, here is a document explaining consistent http://www.maths.nuigalway.ie/~rquinlan/MA203/section1-5.pdf

Comment: The | notation looked like the notation for "determinant", eg: |A| which didn't make any sense for that matrix. So your system of equations is `{1x+hy = 4, 3x+6y=8}` yup?

Comment: For a system of this size, the system is inconsistent if the gradients represented by the lines are the same and the intercepts are different. Do you know how to compute those from the matrix? This is looking a bit like homework.

Comment: Yeah there isn't just a single value that makes it consistent.  As a matter of fact there is a single value that makes it inconsistent and any other value will make it consistent...

Comment: Spacedman, yes,  the matrix is consistent when h != 2. I know how to solve by hand. I want to know how to solve the matrix using R, if possible.

Comment: Let me reword the problem: Using R how do I enter an unknown constant in a matrix so R can calculate the  Reduced Row-Echelon Form?